# Displaying a Crosstab Query with Variable Fields in a Subform

Tags: ms-access, report, parent-child, crosstab, subform

Microsoft Access 2010 here. Working with reports (and forms).

I have a crosstab query that transforms (w/ UNION ALL, thank you Bluefeet!) and pivots another "source query" with the purpose of making the results more coherent to the reader. The source query has fields that do not change, but rows that do, as the source query only selects results from the past 30 days; the fields of the subsequent crosstab query are not expected to stay the same upon requery as the rows have become the fields and vice-versa. What I am wondering is how one would display such a crosstab query in a subform as-is; i.e. as a simple reference with no record-dependence.

An example of the variable fields in the crosstab query:

```
Criteria     | 11/26/2012 | 11/27/2012 | 11/29/2012 | 12/6/2012 ...
# Insp       | 7          | 8          | 8          | 9
# Passed     | 5          | 4          | 5          | 7
# Failed     | 2          | 4          | 3          | 2
% Acceptance | 71%        | 50%        | 63%        | 78%
```

I have successfully tied the crosstab query to a subform "child" for display through it's "Source Object" property, and achieved the desired end-result, but there was the record selection bar which is undesired for a reference, and the option to display it, normally found on forms/subforms is gone on the subform "child."

This leaves me wondering if there is another way to do display crosstab queries in subforms, or if I am looking in the total wrong direction to achieve the task. The report includes a graph based on the source query and below that is to be the crosstab query, displayed purely for reference. Thank you for the help!

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You can display the data in the subform as a query object, what are you missing?

Comment: Its just that the "record selectors" are present with no way to turn them off when the crosstab query is set as the source object of a subform child. It is quite confusing. I can't have static fields in the subform as the crosstab does not comply.

Comment: You are using a shortcut, as it were. You can create a form and map your dates to a fixed name, Day1 or Qtr1 for example.

Comment: In the crosstab the number of columns changes based on the number of days there were in the last 30 days that had inspections. It can scale from 0 days to all 30. Do I map the potential 30 columns with dynamic names to 30 different labels? Thanks for the help and understanding!

Comment: I have just had another idea that may suit better, and that is to create a pivot form. You can follow the wizard under More Forms on the Create ribbon. It will update itself with any days found. See if it suits before we try another path.

Comment: I see using the "PivotTable" under "More Forms" directly with the database groups the dates into columns, though the calculated fields from the query were inaccessible. Attaching the crosstab to a pivot table as a source would not work as the fields were static. Hmm. That tool might work if I could have calculated fields, but it does not seem that is its intended function. Thank you again.